# angularJS ng-table $data not recognized in ng-repeat and no headers is shown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use ng-table but I am having problem with headers and ng-repeat

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" template-pagination="custom/pager" class="table table-bordered table-striped b-t b-light">           
            <tbody>
              <div ng-repeat="row in $data track by row.Id" class="table-row">

<div data-title="'pair'" filter="{ 'pair': 'text' }" sortable="'pair'" class="table-name-cell table-cell pointer ui-sortable-handle">
```

nothing is shown.If I use

```
<div ng-repeat="row in tableParams.data track by row.Id" class="table-row">
```

then I can see data but without any headers. Why I can not see headers by default? And why $data is not working as is written in docs

> DataResults DataResults: T[] & { visibleColumnCount: number; } Defined
>   in src/core/data/results.ts:13 The augmented data row array displayed
>   by the table. Note: this array is made available to the table templete
>   as the $data fiel

EDIT:

I am not using tr, td tags but div tags. Is this important?

AngularJS code

```
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 10
                /*sorting: {
                    time: 'asc'
                }*/
            }, {
                total: 0,
                filterDelay: 300,
                getData: function (params) {
                    return service.search(urlAddress, (params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.count(), params.filter(), params.sorting())
                              .$promise.then(
                                // success
                                function (result) {
                                    scope.items = result.items;
                                    params.total(result.totalCount);

                                    scope.$root.showSpinner = false;
                                    return result.items;
                                },
                                //error
                                function (error) {
                                    scope.$root.showSpinner = false;
                                    webMessageService.addError('Error while reading data: ' + error.data);
                                }
                            );
                }
            });
$scope.tableParams.reload();
```

Comment: post your angularjs code also

Comment: code updated in thread